# Spring validator does not detect errors

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

This code is creating a hmtl form where you can select some chekcboxes and design a Taco. I am trying to perform model fields validation but it is not working. This code for example is supposed to return an error if the input field box of the name is empty or if no checkboxes are selected at all. The error variable in the controller though never catches any errors. What could possibly be happening. This code a copy paste example from the Spring in Action book so I'm not sure why it's not working.

Model

```
@Data
public class Taco {

 @NotNull
 @Size(min=5, message = "Name must be at least 5 characters long")
 private String name;
 @Size(min=1, message = "You must choose at least 1 ingredient")
 private List<String> ingredients;
}
```

Controller

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
public class DesignTacoController {

@GetMapping
public String showDesignFromModel(Model model){
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
            new Ingredient("FLTO","Flour Tortilla", WRAP),
            new Ingredient("COTO","Corn Tortilla", WRAP),
            new Ingredient("GRBF","Ground Beef", PROTEIN),
            new Ingredient("CARN","Carnitas", PROTEIN),
            new Ingredient("TMTP","Diced Tomatoes", VEGGIES),
            new Ingredient("LETC","Lettuce", VEGGIES),
            new Ingredient("CHED","Cheddar", CHEESE),
            new Ingredient("JACK","Monterrey Jack", CHEESE),
            new Ingredient("SLSA","Salsa", SAUCE),
            new Ingredient("SRCR","Sour Cream", SAUCE)
    );


    Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
    for (Type type : types){
        model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),
                ingredients.stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getType() == type)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    }
    model.addAttribute("design",new Taco());
    return "design";
}

@PostMapping
public String processDesign(@Valid Taco design , Errors errors){
    if(errors.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println("Many errors " + errors);
        return "design";
    }
    System.out.println("Process design: " + design);
    System.out.println("No errors " + errors);
    log.info("Process design: " + design);
    return "redirect:/orders/current";
}
}
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
   <title>Taco Cloud</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>Design your taco!</h1>
<img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}" alt="Taco Cloud Logo"/>
<form method="POST" th:object="${design}">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="wraps">
           <h3>Designate your wrap:</h3>
           <div th:each="ingredient : ${wrap}">
               <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
               <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="proteins">
            <h3>Pick your protein:</h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${protein}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="cheeses">
            <h3>Choose your cheese:</h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${cheese}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="veggies">
            <h3>Determine your veggies:</h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${veggies}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ingredient-group" id="sauces">
            <h3>Select your sauce:</h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient : ${sauce}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Name your taco creation:</h3>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Error</span>
        <br/>
        <button>Submit your taco</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What happens when you don't check in at all and the name field is empty?

Comment: I get no errors at all. The controller simply redirects to odrder/current instead of going back to design view and displying the errors.

Comment: try to with adding  @ModelAttribute in `processDesign(@Valid @ModelAttribute("design") Taco design , Errors errors)`

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: (Not so) Wild gues. You have `javax.validation` on the classpath but no implementation (or decided to be smart and use the newest Hibernate Validator instead of the version mentioned in the book, which doesn't work as that is a Jakarta Validation implementation).

Comment: @M.Deinum your guess was correct. The book did not specify any version of validator in the dependancies because it says that it is part of spring boot's web transient dependancies that do not work for me for some reason and thus I had to manually import the validator in the pom file and I used the 7.0.1.Final version which is Jakarta. Worked fine when i switched to 6.2.0 Final version. Do you wish to leave a proper answer I can accept? Perhaps explain a bit more the whole Jakarta thing.

Comment: Which means you use a newer version of `spring-boot-starter-web` as opposed to the book. The validation was removed and moved to `spring-boot-starter-validation` in later versions of Spring Boot. So add that starter.

Comment: Yes, already did that, thanks.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the tip about ```spring-boot-starter-validation```! That was new to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When validation isn't working there is generally one thing that isn't right. There is no implementation for the `javax.validation` API on the classpath. Only adding a dependency to the `validation-api` from `javax.validation` will do nothing as that is only the API not an actual implementation.

You will need to add an implementation, like `hibernate-validator`,  as well.

Now in earlier versions of Spring Boot (prior to 2.3) the validation was automatically included when adding `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency. However in newer version (2.3+) this has been [removed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19550). You now need to explicitly include the  `spring-boot-starter-validation` starter dependency. This includes the API and an implementation.

That being said it could also be that instead of the Java Validation API you have the Jakarta Validation API on the classpath as well as an implementation of that (like `hibernate-validator` version 7 or up). The Jakarata Validation API (or most of the JakartaEE APIs) aren't support (yet) by Spring or Spring Boot. So even if you have that on your classpath it won't work, you need the Java Validation API one.

Answer (score 1):

I was also tortured by this problem for a while 
**Reason:**
If you dont select any CheckBox, ingredients=null ,@Size min dont validate the null result.So, we need combine @NotNull.

```java
@NotNull(message = "You must choose at least 1 ingredient")
@Size(min = 1, message = "You must choose at least 1 ingredient")
private List<String> ingredients;
```